# PhoneGap notification.alert Won't Show the Marker Position

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, cordova, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to show to the user the location of a `marker` using PhoneGap's [`navigator.notification.alert`](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_notification_notification.md.html#Notification) like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
    navigator.notification.alert(
        marker.position,
        "Marker Position",
        "Done"
    );
});
```

But this when the popup comes the title is there, but the body text won't. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I made it to work by converting the position to a `String` using `.toString()`, like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
    var location = marker.position;

    navigator.notification.alert(
        location.toString(),
        "Marker Position",
        "Done"
    );
});
```